# Regular expression in Objective c to extract data between double quotes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Hi all need help in creating a Regular expression in objective c that extracts data between double quotes

"Hello,everyone","Need ,a ,help",,"with",,"a","Regular Expression"

so i need this as

Hello,everyone
Need a help

with

a
Regular expression

in an array. please suggest a solution for this.Thank you

Comment: Yow need to try something, a best effort, and post the code along with example data and what is wrong. A good starting point is `NSRegularExpression` and ICU User Guide [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution, you could do something like the following, using "capturing parentheses" to capture everything between the quotation marks:

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\"(.*?)\"" options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(regex, @"regex error: %@", error);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *found = [string substringWithRange:range];
    // do something with `found`
}];
```

If you wanted to handle string values in which the quotation marks that were escaped with, for example, a backslash, you could use a negative look-behind assertion, too, something like:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)\"" options:0 error:&error];
```

Even that's not perfect (what if the backslash escape character was, itself, escaped), but maybe this is enough to get you going without getting lost in a rat's nest of regex.